# PHP Sort array of arrays by object key

Tags: php, arrays, forms, sorting, ksort

I have a form where I'm creating a number of item arrays:

```
<input type="hidden" value="Full/Double Mattress" name="pickup1-dropoff1Items[1][0]">
<input type="text" name="pickup1-dropoff1Items[1][1]">
<input type="hidden" value="20" name="pickup1-dropoff1Items[1][2]">
<input type="hidden" value="FMat" name="pickup1-dropoff1Items[1][3]">
<input type="hidden" value="1" name="pickup1-dropoff1Items[1][4]">
```

so the structure is basically:

```
array(
    array('title', quantity, price, 'shorthand', order),
    array('title', quantity, price, 'shorthand', order)
)
```

etc...

I'm getting this information using PHP and sending it in an email. I can get one of these arrays like so:

```
$pickup1_dropoff1Items = $_POST['pickup1-dropoff1Items'];
```

I would like to sort the arrays in `$pickup1_dropoff1Items` by the 'order' number (i.e. index #4, i.e. `$pickup1-dropoff1Items[i][4]`) in each of those arrays.

Can this be done using PHP ksort()? Does anyone have any idea how to sort an array like this using PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not tested but I think this will do what you need:

```
// first create a new array of just the order numbers 
// in the same order as the original array
$orders_index = array();
foreach( $pickup1_dropoff1Items as $item ) {
  $orders_index[] = $item[4];
}

// then use a sort of the orders array to sort the original
// array at the same time (without needing to look at the 
// contents of the original)
array_multisort( $orders_index, $pickup1_dropoff1Items );
```

This is essentially example 1 here:
http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-multisort.php
but our `$ar2` is an array of arrays instead of an array of single values. Also if you need more control over the sort you'll see examples of options you can use at that URL: just add them to the list of arguments for `array_multisort`.

Comment: $orders_index = array();

not $orders_index = [];

Comment: Make that correction and I'll mark it right!

Comment: I think someone already made it for me, thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

For sorting complex arrays like this, you can use something like [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) which "sorts an array by values using a user-defined comparison function".

See the example on php.net for more information.